# How to keep the first value by two groups using SAS

Tags: sas, group

I have a sample data that has three columns (Row, ID, and Level) and 10 rows. ID1 has 6 rows and ID2 has 4 rows.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QtxTC.png)

I want to create a new column Level1. This new column is created based on Level by a rule: if Level moves from Moderate to Severe, then Level1 from Moderate to Severe. But if Level moves from Severe to Moderate then Level1 keeps all the rest as Severe (from the first Severe). Here for ID1, from Row 1 to Row 4, Level moves from Moderate to Severe, so Level1 is the same as Level from Moderate to Severe. But from Row 5, Level moves from Severe to Moderate, so the rest (Row 5 to Row 6) of ID1 both are Severe. For ID2, since all move from Moderate to Severe, Level is the same as Level1.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UpD7b.png)

Answer (score 1):

Use RETAIN to keep value of LEVEL1 the same until you explicitly change it.

```
data want;
  set have;
  by id;
  if first.id then level1=level;
  if level='Severe' then level1=level;
  retain level1;
run;
```